# How to add paper_trail as dependency to Spree extension?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, spree, paper-trail-gem

I'm creating a new spree extension, with paper_trail gem dependency. So, i want track models changes (products and orders).
Then, When try to start rails application, i get this error:

```
undefined local variable or method `has_paper_trail'
```

My rails app Gemfile:

```
gem 'spree_blameable', path: '/spree_blameable'
```

My order_decorator.rb it's very simple:

```
Spree::Order.class_eval do
  has_paper_trail
end
```

My gemspec:

```
s.add_dependency 'spree_core', '~> 2.1.4'
s.add_dependency 'paper_trail', '~> 3.0.0'
```

What is it I'm missing?

Edit: Just add gem 'paper_trail', '~> 3.0.0' in Gemfile

Excuse my grammar, Greetings

Comment: Out of curiousity, is this extension open source somewhere? I'm sure other people would love to have this functionality.

Comment: @GeekOnCoffee Sure, check https://github.com/acidlabs/spree_papertrail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add gem 'paper_trail', '~> 3.0.0' in Gemfile

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
require 'paper_trail'
```

to your `config/application.rb` after it includes 'rails/all'.